An echo that sounds for years?
How exactly should I understand United Airlines Flight 2860's description and English Wikipedia? Namely, last sentence of the fourth chapter of the summary:

The "echo" of the crash could be seen on the mountainside for several years afterward

Is it truly possible that some sound wave exists (resonates?) for years?
And why "echo" is given in quotation marks? Is this a "different" echo in this case? Or are we speaking about the same effect that I get, when I shout in the mountains?
I was more than sure that I am not an ignorant in physics. But it seems I am, because I was more than sure that any sound wave emitted gets dissolved in a matter of seconds or maybe a minute. Even the one that carries energy generated during large airliner explosion.
I thought that an echo effect or sound wave, strong enough, can cause an avalanche. But not, that it can last for weeks, months or years.
What am I missing?

It surely is not referring to an acoustic echo. It seems most likely to me, that by "echo" they mean the visible remains of the plane, but that's weirdly metaphorical language. Certainly confusing and poor style for Wikipedia.

@David_h We strongly discourage answering in comments.  Apart from anything else, you can get reputation points for an answer.  Comments should ideally be used only to seek clarification of a question or answer.

The word echo can be used for more than just sounds of course, it doesn't even have to be metaphorical, but as such this isn't a physics question per se.

it's an English idiom.

Probably "scar" would have been a more apt metaphor.

While Physics.SE can confirm that this is almost certainly not an acoustic echo, English.SE could probably do a better job of describing what was intended by the phrase.

It surely is not referring to an acoustic echo. It seems most likely to me, that by "echo" they mean the visible remains of the plane, but that's weirdly metaphorical language. Certainly confusing and poor style for Wikipedia.

In my question, I am asking (not directly, but still) how long can a typical acoustic echo last ("because I was more than sure that any sound wave emitted gets dissolved in a matter of seconds or maybe a minute"). Worth expanding answer by this?

@trejder probably better to ask that as a question of its own, so you can get an answer from somebody who knows about that. My short googling just says theirs a Guinness record, and depending on how you measure, it's between a minute and two. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273783322_A_record_longest_echo_within_the_Inchindown_oil_despository

The dent in the mountain the aircraft caused is still to be seen. So it has nothing to do with sound. The german wiki side just tells it without calling it an echo.
From Wikipedia's German site:

"Die Aufprallstelle war noch Jahre nach dem Unfall deutlich am Berghang zu erkennen."

translation :

The impact site was still clearly visible on the mountainside years after the accident.


It might be useful to show what the German site says and what that translates as.

As asked I cite: "Die Aufprallstelle war noch Jahre nach dem Unfall deutlich am Berghang zu erkennen." translation :The impact site was still clearly visible on the mountainside years after the accident.
